# JQuery making ajax options dynamic

Tags: javascript, ajax

right now in my `$.ajax({ ..});` call I have the following option:

```
data: { param0: param0, param1: param1}
```

Say I want the number of parameters to by dynamic (based on a variable passed to the function in which the ajax call is made).  How do I provide `data:` a dynamic set of parameters?  I think I need to somehow construct an object (?) ahead of time (i.e. before the ajax call) and then pass this object to `data:`..but I'm not sure how to do this.

By variable passed in, I mean optional parameters which will be used as the GET params: param2 and param3 if they are passed in. So:

```
function myAjaxCall(param0, param1, param2, param3) { // param2/3 are optional
  $.ajax({
      //...
      data: { param0: param0, param1: param1} // this will need param2/3 if passed in
      //..
  });
}
```

So depending on if param2 and param3 are passed in (either, none or both is valid) I need the data object constructed accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you need to make an object out of your parameters and pass it as data:

```
var mydata = {
    name: 'ali',
    email: 'ali@example.com',
    ...
}

$.ajax({
    ...
    data: mydata,
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of the automatically created **[`arguments` array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)**.

```
function myAjaxCall() {
 $.ajax({
   data: arguments, // "arguments" is an Array Object created automatically by JS
   ...
 });
}
```

or, if you want it to be an object literal with the arguments array as a property:

```
function myAjaxCall() {
 $.ajax({
   data: {args: arguments}, // "arguments" is an Array Object 
    ...                     //   created automatically by JS
 });
}
```

You can call this with any number of parameters, and **[the parameters can be any data form](http://jsfiddle.net/fh9ru/)**.

```
myAjaxCall({ fruit: "apple"}, "blah", 500, true);
```

Note that `arguments` is read only, so if you want to work with it, you have to copy it, and `arguments.splice(0)` will not work.... you have to use a for loop.

To check how many arguments were passed in, simply look at `arguments.length`.

Comment: This is great, but lots of frameworks (I know ASP.Net) have trouble with arrays for JSON parameters, you are better off passing an object with a property that is the array. Granted, the array is valid JSON, I know, but in practice it's much more of a pain to deal with.

Comment: @sworoc - Then just add the array to an object.

Comment: Which is what I said at the end of my first sentence, glad we agree! :)

Comment: @sworoc - Edited to include that form too.